# pythons files are being ignored with pyproject.toml

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

the python files are ignored under src(mlm) directory. I have included the `mlm` directory in `where` for finding packages.

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"


[project]
name = "arichuvadi"
version = "0.0.3"
authors = [
  { name="vanangamudi", email="sgfrecfs@gmail.com" },
]
description = "a basic set of tools to work with Tamil text"
readme = "YENNAI_PADI.txt"
license = { file="LICENSE" }
requires-python = ">=3.5"
classifiers = [
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "Operating System :: OS Independent",
]

[project.urls]

[tool.setuptools]
include-package-data = true

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src"]  # ["."] by default
include = ["*.py"]  # ["*"] by default
exclude = []  # empty by default
namespaces = true  # true by default
```

and here is the directory layout of the project

```
(arichuvadi)$ tree
.
├── LICENSE
├── MANIFEST.in
├── src
│   ├── arichuvadi.py
│   ├── orunguri-tha.py
│   ├── tharavu
│   │   ├── adaiyalamitta-ari.txt
│   │   ├── ari.txt
│   │   └── ari-uni.txt
│   └── valam.py
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.org -> YENNAI_PADI.txt
├── setup.py
└── YENNAI_PADI.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `src` directory simply does not contain a python package (or module) due to a missing  `__init__.py`. You should arrive at something like this:

```
.
├── LICENSE
├── MANIFEST.in
├── src
│   ├── my_actual_package_name
│   |   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── arichuvadi.py
│   │   ├── orunguri-tha.py
│   │   ├── tharavu
│   │   │   ├── adaiyalamitta-ari.txt
│   │   │   ├── ari.txt
│   │   │   └── ari-uni.txt
│   │   └── valam.py
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.org -> YENNAI_PADI.txt
├── setup.py
└── YENNAI_PADI.txt
```

You should also make sure to setup package_data configuration if you want to include the txt files in your package.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can do this without changing your directory tree:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"


[project]
name = "arichuvadi"
version = "0.0.3"
authors = [
  { name="vanangamudi", email="sgfrecfs@gmail.com" },
]
description = "a basic set of tools to work with Tamil text"
readme = "YENNAI_PADI.txt"
license = { file="LICENSE" }
requires-python = ">=3.5"
classifiers = [
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "Operating System :: OS Independent",
]

[project.urls]

[tool.setuptools]
packages = ["src"]
```

Also if you have pyproject.toml, you don't necessarily need setup.py anymore.